# YarnAllocator requests containers more than I asked for

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, resourcemanager

YarnAllocator and Yarn Resource Manager acted so generously that it requested and gave more than I put on the config. I asked for a total of 72 containers and it gave 133 containers. What I expect is that YarnAllocator will allocate only how many I asked. Can someone please explain what happened?

And here are the requests captured from logs

```
18/06/08 06:52:29 INFO yarn.YarnAllocator: Will request 72 executor container(s), each with 4 core(s) and 11264 MB memory (including 3072 MB of overhead)
18/06/08 06:52:29 INFO yarn.YarnAllocator: Submitted 72 unlocalized container requests.
...
18/06/08 06:52:30 INFO yarn.YarnAllocator: Will request 8 executor container(s), each with 4 core(s) and 11264 MB memory (including 3072 MB of overhead)
18/06/08 06:52:30 INFO yarn.YarnAllocator: Submitted 8 unlocalized container requests.
...
18/06/08 06:52:31 INFO yarn.YarnAllocator: Will request 53 executor container(s), each with 4 core(s) and 11264 MB memory (including 3072 MB of overhead)
18/06/08 06:52:32 INFO yarn.YarnAllocator: Submitted 53 unlocalized container requests.
```

Here are my spark config:

```
--driver-memory 4g \
--executor-memory 8g \
--executor-cores 4 \
--num-executors 72 \
--conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=3072 \
--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-XX:+UseG1GC" \
--conf spark.yarn.max.executor.failures=128 \
--conf spark.memory.fraction=0.1 \
--conf spark.rdd.compress=true \
--conf spark.shuffle.compress=true \
--conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true \
--conf spark.shuffle.spill.compress=true \
--conf spark.speculation=false \
--conf spark.task.maxFailures=1000 \
--conf spark.sql.codegen.wholeStage=false \
--conf spark.scheduler.listenerbus.eventqueue.size=100000 \
--conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=false \
```

Comment: Executors may come and go. Can you check the logs if some were replaced by new ones (after a failure)?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I check the logs and there's no executor replacement happened. And I did not see any errors/fail.